# How to get variable outside the TEST-INJECTION?

Tags: abap

I would like to have an access to variable outside TEST-INJECTION scope. To clarify, what I mean, consider the following example:

```
DATA lt_doc_import TYPE zcl_za_doc_cleaner=>tt_doc_protocol.
MOVE-CORRESPONDING mo_dc_cleaner->mt_doc_import TO lt_doc_import.

TEST-INJECTION query_doc_protocol.
  rt_doc_protocol = lt_doc_import.
END-TEST-INJECTION.

DATA(lt_protocol) = mo_dc_cleaner->query_doc_protocol( ).

mo_dc_cleaner->filter_delete_protocol(
  EXPORTING
    it_doc_import = mo_dc_cleaner->mt_doc_import
    it_doc_protocol = lt_protocol
  IMPORTING
    et_doc_import = mo_dc_cleaner->mt_doc_import
    et_msg = DATA(lt_msg)
).

DESCRIBE TABLE lt_msg LINES DATA(lv_msg).
DESCRIBE TABLE mo_dc_cleaner->mt_doc_import LINES DATA(lv_doc_import).
```

The compiler is complaining, that the variable lt_doc_import is unknown. How to get the variable outside from `TEST-INJECTION`?

Comment: Something is wrong. You already have your access to the variable outside `TEST-INJECTION ... END-TEST-INJECTION`in this statement `MOVE-CORRESPONDING mo_dc_cleaner->mt_doc_import TO lt_doc_import.`. Anyway, thanks I did not know that such a thing even exist. At the first sight looks unfortunately as cluttering the productive code with `TEST-SEAM... END-TEST-SEAM`.

Comment: If it is allow to take the scope into `TEST-INJECTION` then, then it would be wonderful.

Comment: I can not assign the variable defined outside `TEST-INJECTION ... END-TEST-INJECTION` in the `TEST-INJECTION ... END-TEST-INJECTION` self.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotation from the SAP [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abaptest-injection.htm) on the topic has it that...

> Injections cannot access types and objects that are not visible in the location of the specified test seam.
>
> This applies in particular to types and objects of the test class and test method defined in the injection. These types and objects are placed in the location of the statement TEST-INJECTION, but are not visible in the injection.

So unfortunately it is not possible to access the variables that are in the same scope as `TEST-INJECTION`. You can only access the variables that are also visible in the same scope as `TEST-SEAM`.

Comment: "Test seams" are to be used as last resort only when you have to deal with "legacy" programs. The classic way to inject alternate data or code is to use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: I am afraid this feature might be abused.

Comment: [Clean ABAP: Use test seams as temporary workaround](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md#use-test-seams-as-temporary-workaround)

Comment: Seems I have a lot to catch up with. I have been waiting for such a class like `CL_ABAP_TESTDOUBLE` for years. Did not know that SAP finally managed to create something like that. Thanks Florian for this reference!